# How to get the brackets in the multirow spanning all three rows?

Tags: brackets

I'm constructing a table, where I have a multirow spanning 3rows in the center of this table. For examples, from row 6 to 8 in center of the table. This is hard because the brackets have to be located only center position.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\toprule
Type & VoVNet & Output \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Stem} & 3$\times$3 conv, 64,  stride=2 & 112$\times$112 \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & 3$\times$3 conv, 64,  stride=1 & 112$\times$112 \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & 3$\times$3 conv, 128, stride=1 & 112$\times$112 \\ \hline
Pooling & 3$\times$3 max pool, stride=2 & 56$\times$56 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 2\end{tabular}} & {[}3$\times$3, conv, 128{]} $\times$ 5 & 56$\times$56 \\ 
 & concatenate \& {[}1$\times$1 conv, 128{]} & 56$\times$56 \\
 & 3$\times$3 max pool, stride=2 & 28$\times$28 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 3\end{tabular}} & {[}3$\times$3, conv, 160{]} $\times$ 5 & 28$\times$28 \\
 & concatenate \& {[}1$\times$1 conv, 256{]} & 28$\times$28 \\
 & 3$\times$3 max pool, stride=2 & 14$\times$14 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 4A\end{tabular}} & {[}3$\times$3, conv, 192{]} $\times$ 5 & 14$\times$14 \\
 & concatenate \& {[}1x1 conv, 512{]} & 14$\times$14 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 4B\end{tabular}} & {[}3$\times$3, conv, 224{]} $\times$ 5 & 14$\times$14 \\
 & concatenate \& {[}1$\times$1 conv, 512{]} & 14$\times$14 \\
 & 3$\times$3 max pool, stride=2 & 7$\times$7 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ estage 5A\end{tabular}} & {[}3$\times$3, conv, 256{]} $\times$ 5 & 7$\times$7 \\
 & concatenate \& {[}1$\times$1 conv, 1024{]} & 7$\times$7 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DRF block\\ stage 5B\end{tabular}} & {[}3$\times$3, conv, 288{]} $\times$ 5 & 7$\times$7 \\
 & concatenate \& {[}1$\times$1 conv, 1024{]} & 7$\times$7 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{ Overall architecture of VoVNet. VoVNet is compose of 39 convolution layers. Note that each "conv" layer has the sequence Conv-BN-ReLU.}
\label{tb:VoVNet}
\vspace{-0.35cm}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This request is not very clear. Do you mean a `brace` (`{`) as  in the `cases` environment) at the beginning of the 3rows in the second column? Or a real bracket (`[`)? And happens to the vertical rules then?

Comment: @Bernard, real bracket "[" to the vertical rules